# Problema con mi pagina web - failed to load resource

Tags: html, css, html5, web, hosting

**Hola a todos.**

tengo un pequeño problema con mi sitio, no me carga algunos archivos de estilo que utilizo en mi web.

me aparece mensajes de Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

no se, si tengo mal las rutas donde cargo los archivos, las tengo de la siguiente manera.

CSS

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:url('../icomoon.eot');
  src:url('../icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('../icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../icomoon.svg') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  }
  
   @font-face {
  font-family: 'flexslider-icon';
  src: url('../fonts/themify-icons/flexslider-icon.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/themify-icons/flexslider-icon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/flexslider-icon.svg#flexslider-icon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

index

```html
<!-- Animate.css -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
 <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
 <!-- Themify Icons-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themify-icons.css">
 <!-- Bootstrap  -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
```

Este el directorio que tengo de los archivos es en un host.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado poner la ruta de varias formas y no me agarra los archivos, o nose si es un problemas de permisos con las carpetas del host.

Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Las rutas que tienes en css apunta a la carpeta raiz, falta llevarlas a la carpeta fonts
Sustituye

```
src:url('../icomoon.eot');
```

Por

```
src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot');
```

Comment: ya lo puse asi, y sigue igual

Comment: Quita los dos puntos e inicia con `/`

Comment: si gue igual, me voy a volver loco

Comment: @Darklawz esta respuesta debería funcionar, añade más detalles. Por ej, ve a la ruta que te marca el Inspector de Elementos y mira si realmente existe en tu directorio. Otra recomendación, es incluir la ruta directamente en la URL del font-face, algo así: `src:url('https://bodyscan.hn/css/icomoon.eot');`